# My HttpGet call to retieve my stream, sometimes stops and doesn't continue, even after timeout

Tags: android, asynchronous, inputstream, http-get

I use to make two types of httpGet call. One for parsing JSON with Gson and one for getting the string, for small JSONs....

This is what I use for parsing with GSON:

```
    static HttpGet getRequest;
static HttpResponse getResponse;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    int timeout = 30000;
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeout);
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {

        getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);

        final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ERROR", "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
            return null;
        }

        HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

        return getResponseEntity.getContent();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ERROR", "Error for URL " + url, e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ERROR", "Error for URL " + url, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

- Yes, almost always, if there are some errors on JSON or there's no connection, it gives me `null` and I handle it.
- Yes, almost always, if JSON is correct and I have connection, I can parse it successfully.
- **But few times**, I think around 10 or 11 in one month, **it doesn't do anything**. It **stops** and **doesn't continue** (I let it for 20 minutes). It doesn't return null due to URL error, JSON error or TIMEOUT, it just stops. In that moment, my connection is stopped (no movements) but my connection works normally (because I receive messages from, for example WhatsApp).
  So, if I open a `ProgressDialog`, it never closes because I can't handle a null or a successful InputStream, so I can't make the user know that, in the worst of the cases, he/she has to retry.

I'm making all this stuff **asynchronously**.

What am I doing bad?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lowering the Thread policy is bad practise. Consider using an `AsyncTask`. If you are already doing this stuff asynchronously, you can remove the thread policy modification.

Comment: Done, but problem still happens.